# Redirect only on Flutter Web

Tags: javascript, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm trying to set up an app that uses a WebView (flutter_webview on pub) on Android and redirects directly on web, as flutter_webview does not work on web. I looked into js on pub and dart:js but that does not work, as Android doesn't allow dart:js or package:js to be imported at all. Any ideas? I'm using kIsWeb to detect the platform (not offering iOS or Desktop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in web, just create a method like this:

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

void openInWindow(String uri, String name) {
  html.window.open(uri, name);
}
```

and use it like this:

```
print('heading over to... $uri');
openInWindow(uri.toString(), '_self');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires dart:html which is also broken on Android.

Comment: The `universal_html` package works on all platforms.

Comment: As Andrej says it's easiest to use universal_html. Equally you could use conditional imports: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#conditionally-importing-and-exporting-library-files Write two versions of your redirect method, one for each platform, put them in separate source files and import the relevant one depending on the platform.

Answer (score 0):

import 'dart:html' as html; dont forget this import for previous solution

Comment: Since you are adding additional details to an existing answer, you should Edit the answer with the new details or just add them to the comments.